# min-width not working on any browser

Tags: html, css, width, min

I am trying to set min-width: 800px but it is not working, I have done exactly the same thing on other projects and it has worked fine, I have tried it on both chrome and ie but no difference. I have seen a lot of people have problems with this in ie but as it doesnt work in chrome either I am stuck.

Here is a trial of it working: http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/

HI have also made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wDGG/

Some of the JS isn't working as it should in the fiddle but I doubt that's important, it works on the my tests in browser so no worries.

I'll also include the CSS here:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
}

.navigation {
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 60px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f27009;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#nav-center {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #f27009;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: dashed 1px #000000;
    border-top: dashed 1px #000000;
    left: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav-center ul {
    margin: 0;
}

#nav-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}

#nav-left {
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(images/banner_left.png);
    margin: 0px 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

#nav-right {
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(images/banner_right.png);
    margin: 0px 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

.active {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
}

a {
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#home {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}

#section1 {
    background-color: #1899d6;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#section2 {
    background-color: #CF0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#section3 {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It is working for me. Chrome. I suppose you havent understand what `min-width` does

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to **not** restrict the width of the `body` but rather throw a wrapper on the lot and add a min-width to that?

Comment: That is pretty much what I had to do but with a few other changes as seen below in the comment by Xdevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `min-width:800px` to the `navigation` class too, take a look to that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wDGG/1/).

Comment: That has sorted the nav bar out now but I have a pic (nav-right) which is fixed top right and need to stop moving once the window hits 800px, I thought that by setting the body to min-width: 800px it would apply to any child elements within the body, is that wrong? Maybe I need a container div which holds all element of the nav bar which is fixed top and then set the two nav caps at either side to float? I will try and get a trial version of it running live so you can see all elements working together.

Comment: I put your bar in the correct position just adding another container for you'r nav bar with google chrome inspector.
Just folow that steps:
1-Add another container for the nav bar.
2-The container of the 3 nav bar elements must have `position:relative` and `width:100%;height:100%;`
3-The parent of that container is the fixed one.
4-The 3 elements of the nav bar must have `position:absolute;`
5-Just move the elements with inspector until you have the correct position.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, the only thing I had to do differently was set width: calc(100% - 120px); on .navigation - If you want to see it working you can see it at zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com (it may change slightly as I work on the rest of the page).